# how to get custom made object from ObjectMapper in java

Tags: java

I am doing the following:

```
IronRunId Id = new IronRunId("RunObject", "Runid1", 4);
ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("RunId", Id);
String json = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(map);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
IronRunId runId = (IronRunId) (map1.get("RunId"));
```

But this gives me an error: Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap to IronRunId
Why is the object returned by map.get() of type linkedhashmap?

On the contrary, if I do:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
myList.add("Jonh");
myList.add("Jack");
map.put("list", myList);
```

Then the object returned by map.get() after doing mapper.readValue is of type ArrayList.

Why the difference? Inserting default types into the map returns the correct object. But inserting custom made object in the map does not.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you using Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

basically translated to, *return me a Map with keys of type String and values of type Object*. So, Jackson gave you keys of type `String` and  values of type `Object`. Jackson doesn't know about your custom object, thats why it gave you its own native bound for `Object` which is a `Map`, specifically, a `LinkedHashMap`, and thus the reason why your are getting a `LinkedHashMap` when doing a `get` to the returned `Map`

So change it to :

```
Map<String, IronRunId> map1 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, IronRunId>>() {});
```

Also, it is a good practice to declare an Object of its interface type than its concrete type. So instead of

`HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

make it

`Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

**Edit**

As a response to your added questions, you can create a wrapper object that will handle all your objects. Something like this.

```
class Wrapper{

    private IronRunId ironRunId;
    private long time;
    private Map<String, String> aspects;
    private String anotherString;

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getAspects() {
        return aspects;
    }
    public void setAspects(Map<String, String> aspects) {
        this.aspects = aspects;
    }
    public String getAnotherString() {
        return anotherString;
    }
    public void setAnotherString(String anotherString) {
        this.anotherString = anotherString;
    }
    public IronRunId getIronRunId() {
        return ironRunId;
    }
    public void setIronRunId(IronRunId ironRunId) {
        this.ironRunId = ironRunId;
    }
}
```

You can then store different objects in this class.

*Revised version*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    IronRunId Id = new IronRunId("RunObject", "Runid1", 4);
    Map<String, String> aspects = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aspects.put("aspectskey1", "aspectsValue1");
    aspects.put("aspectskey2", "aspectsValue2");
    aspects.put("aspectskey3", "aspectsValue3");
    String anotherString = "anotherString";
    long time = 1L;

    Wrapper objectWrapper = new Wrapper();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    objectWrapper.setIronRunId(Id);
    objectWrapper.setTime(time);
    objectWrapper.setAnotherString(anotherString);
    objectWrapper.setAspects(aspects);

    Map<String, Wrapper> map = new HashMap<String, Wrapper>();
    map.put("theWrapper", objectWrapper);
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);

    Map<String, Wrapper> map1 = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Wrapper>>() {});
    Wrapper wrapper = map1.get("theWrapper");

    System.out.println("run id : " +  wrapper.getIronRunId().toString());
    System.out.println("time : " + wrapper.getTime());
    System.out.println("aspects : " + wrapper.getAspects().toString());
    System.out.println("anotherString : " + wrapper.getAnotherString());
}
```

Comment: This map won't always have objects of type IronRunId. It can have other objects as well. Like: map.put("time", time); -> This time is long. Then map.put("aspects", aspects); -> This aspects is another map of objects. That is why I had written Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(...);  In this case, can you tell me what could be done?

Comment: And even if I put just one type of objects in the map n do: Map<String, IronRunId> map1 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, IronRunId>>() {}); ---> still I get the error as: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class IronRunId]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: Ok I got the 'No Constructor' error resolved. But the question remains that what if my map has objects of different types and not just one type(IronRunId). Basically my map has entries with values of types String, long, map of differnt custom objects, collections. So how do I manage this? Any idea?

Comment: As I had said earlier, I had resolved that error but I am getting the same error now: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Result]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)  I had resolved this issue by adding a no parameter constructor initially and now also I did the same. But I am still getting the same error. I have the no parameter constructor in place and yet I get that error. Any ideas what must be done?

Answer (score 0):

`new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>` is too generic. It is equivalent Map or "untyped" Map mentioned in [Data Binding With Generics](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics). The only way for you to deserialize different datatypes in a map or collection is to use [TypeFactory.parametricType](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html)

Comment: Could you please give me an example?